# How to stop make from adding unicode to passed arguments

Tags: makefile, unicode

I am running a C program on a Linux system from make.

```
> hostnamectl
  ...
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

A numeric argument passed to the program has three bytes prepended to it.  This seems to be unicode describing the byte order.

This is the C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc > 1) {
        while (((argv[1][0] & 0x80) == 0x80) && (argv[1][0] != 0)) {
            printf("skipping unicode header %#x\n", (uint8_t) argv[1][0]);
            argv[1]++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this Makefile:

```
x  = ‭1048570
y  = abcdefg

all:
    gcc test.c -o test
    ./test  1048570
    ./test  abcdefg
    ./test  $(x)
    ./test  $(y)
```

Running make produces this result:

```
> make
gcc test.c -o test
./test  1048570
./test  abcdefg
./test  ‭1048570
skipping unicode header 0xe2
skipping unicode header 0x80
skipping unicode header 0xad
./test  abcdefg
```

Running the program from the command line does not generate any 'skipping' messages.

The real program is running OK but I would like to know where the extra bytes are coming from.

Comment: FYI, the code point is a left-to-right override (U+202D) encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that `make` itself is responsible for the behavior you describe.  My first guess would be that the unexpected bytes are actually present in the makefile.  Given that they code for a non-printing character, your editor might not show them to you. At least, not by default.  If that's so, then `make` is just doing what you told it to do.

Comment: You very likely have unwanted hidden characters in your Makefile. If, from your question, I copy-paste its first line to `cat -A <<< 'x  = ‭1048570'` (to show non-printing characters) here is what I get: `x  = M-bM-^@M--1048570$`. It is you or your editor who add these, not make. You should sanitize your Makefile and, maybe, use an editor that shows you these non-printing characters. Note: `((argv[1][0] & 0x80) == 0x80) && (argv[1][0] != 0)` can be simplified as `(argv[1][0] & 0x80) == 0x80`.

Comment: @John & Renaud - I brought the files home and a different editor shows the extra characters in the make file.  Thanks for the help.